# Is it possible to send an element in an ordered real algebra both to a positive unit and to a negative unit?

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, ordered-rings

Let ${(A, P)}$ be a preordered $\mathbb{R}$-algebra in the sense that $A$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and ${P \subseteq A}$ is a subset closed under addition, multiplication, containing the nonnegative reals and not containing ${-1}$.

Assume also that we are given an ${x, y \in P}$ and  a morphism ${f : (R, P) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})}$ of preordered algebras such that ${f x < f y}$.

Question: Can there exist a ${g : (R, P) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})}$ such that ${g y < g x}$?

Note: I have the impression that under reasonable not too strong hypotheses such a $g$ should not exist. 
So I guess that what I am really asking is for the weakest hypotheses that guarantee that no such $g$ exists. For instance, is lack of direct product decompositions enough? (Of course, requiring $P$ to be totally ordered would be pointless.) Anyway, I don't know if my intuition is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following: let $A=\Bbb R[x,y]$ with $P$ the set of polynomials with all coefficients non-negative. Then $x,y\in P$, and the the morphism $f$ given by evaluating $x=1$ and $y=2$ gives $fx<fy$, but the morphism $g$ given by evaluating $x=2$ and $y=1$ gives $gy<gx$.

I think your intuition could be good if one requires some sort of comparability between $x$ and $y$: for instance, if $y-x \in P$, then you get what you want (though this is maybe too trivial?).

Comment: Concerning intuition,  I was thinking more on conditions on the pair ${(R, P)}$ that would guarantee the non-existence of $g$. Anyway, thanks; perhaps my intuition is just wrong.

Comment: May be you are right about requiring something of $x$ and $y$, @KReiser . The condition ${y - x \in P}$ is too easy; but what about the existence of ${p, q \in P}$ such that ${x p + y q = 1 + x q + y p}$. (This would say that ${x - y}$ is invertible in the ring completion of $P$.)